# Combine Lambda-Expressions dynamic for where

Tags: c#, .net, collections, lambda

I have a list of lambda-expressions `List<Func<SomeObject, bool>> filterList;`
This filterlist is using to filter a collection of `SomeObject` easily like this:

```
List<SomeObject> randomList; //filled with random stuff

foreach (Func<SomeObject, bool> filter in filterlist)
    randomList = randomList.Where(filter).ToList();
```

Now I want to combine some filters - but I want to combine them with AND- or OR-Statements.
As example: The user has 3 filter A,B and C and want to combine them to something like "A && (B || C).

I have no idea howto do this.

Comment: actually you are already combining them all with AND

Comment: How would you know when to combine with AND and when to do it with OR?

Comment: Yeah, but  I want to setup complex filter (example "A && (B || C)"). :P

Comment: My filterlist contains also a name and id. The user chose two filter (B and C) and press a button "combine OR". Now I want to identificate the two rules and combine them to a new single rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Func<T>`, not `Expression<Func<T>>`, which makes it impossible to 'rewrite' them, or combine multiple func's in a single one. So you can only execute them in a certain order.

You are already combining them with AND.

To combine two (or more) criteria with OR, do this:

```
randomList = randomList.Where(x => filter1(x) || filter2(x)).ToList();
```

To do `A && (B || C)`, do this:

```
randomList = randomList.Where(x => filterA(x) && (filterB(x) || filterC(x))).ToList();
```

Comment: Ok, when I use `Expression<Func<SomeObject, bool>>` - how can I "rewrite" them?